# What does detail do or mean in this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone please explain what the a in this function means and how it relates to detail? What does detail do?
I have put it through the debugger in chrome to try and understand it, but no joy. I know that it work, but I would like to know why and how. Thank you.

```
addEventListener('search_box', function(a){
  window.SearchBoxTrigger = a.detail
  trigger()
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event.detail` is part of the `CustomEvent` interface (ie9 +). While creating a CustomEvent, you get to set a detail property which does not have to be a string but can also be an object. Do not forget that the detail has be created in the same window you fired the event from. More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/detail